# Some javascript not executed on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile

I've got a block of javascript code that runs fine on all desktop browsers but not on mobile browsers. It's a chain of multiple AJAX calls that need the results of the previously executed functions so I'm using Jquery's deferred function.
All of the deferred functions are executed properly but the code between {} doesn't appear to be executed at all on mobile.
The last function in the chain, getBasemixIngredients() is executed properly.
'Test' doesn't show up in the console, nor are there any error messages.

```
workplace.getVariables().
then(workplace.getUnits).
then(workplace.getIngredients).
then(workplace.getBasemixes).
then(workplace.getBasemixIngredients).
done(function(){
    console.log('test');
    workplace.initIngredientSelectors();
    workplace.writeBasemix();
    workplace.adjustBasemixIngredients();
    workplace.calculateNutrionValues();
    workplace.calculatePrice();
});
```

I'm curious why this might not work on mobile browsers and how I should go about fixing it.

Comment: Did you check if it's simply a mobile issue or a mobile browser version issue? Doesn't seem like this would be something that would differ at the platform level

Comment: Yeah I checked that, I'm currently testing in Safari 10.0.3 which fully supports ES6.